# Ruby CSV input value format

Tags: ruby, csv

I'm using ruby CSV module to read in a csv file.

One of the values inside the csv file is in format is XXX_XXXXX where X are number. I treat this value as string, actually, but CSV module is reading in these values as XXXXXXXX, as numbers, which I do not want.

Options I am currently using

```
f = CSV.read('file.csv', {:headers => true, :header_converters => :symbol, :converters => :all} )
```

Is there a way to tell CSV to not do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

f = CSV.read('file.csv', {:headers => true, :header_converters => :symbol)}

Leave out the `:converters => :all`; that one tries (amongst others) to convert all numerical looking strings to numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The :convertors => all causes this, try the following

```
require "csv"

CSV.parse(DATA, :col_sep => ",", :headers => true, :converters => :all).each do |row|
  puts row["numfield"]
end
__END__
textfield,datetimefield,numfield
foo,2008-07-01 17:50:55.004688,123_45678
bar,2008-07-02 17:50:55.004688,234_56789

# gives
# 12345678
# 23456789
```

and

```
CSV.parse(DATA, :col_sep => ",", :headers => true).each do |row|
  puts row["numfield"]
end

__END__
textfield,datetimefield,numfield
foo,2008-07-01 17:50:55.004688,123_45678
bar,2008-07-02 17:50:55.004688,234_56789

# gives
# 123_45678
# 234_56789
```

Comment: Thank you! You are right. Unfortunately steenslag answered before with the same answer... so I chose his/her answer. But thank you!!

Comment: yeah, i spended more time documenting my answer, good for the people who hit this in the future, happy coding..